# Вывести всплывающее сообщение в JsonResult, BeginForm

Tags: c#, json

Есть кнопка, она сохраняет измененные данные в инпутах в БД. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выводилось всплывающее окно успешного обновления(чтоб не кидало на другую страницу)? Использую `BeginForm` и `JsonResult`.

Answer (score 1):

Можно вернуть js-код для алерта из контроллера следующим образом:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction() {
    // ...
    var script = @"alert(""Информация была успешно занесена в базу данных."");";
    return JavaScript(script);
}
```

Comment: спасибо. а я уже забыл про это.